# Sync Desktop with online account?

Tags: sync

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Is there a way to keep my desktop synced with an online account (like Dropbox or google drive) so any file I create/edit on my desktop gets updated automatically to the online account and vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Sparkleshare for that. Think of Sparkle as "auto git". All file modifications are committed and sent to remote. Works well, with the power of git version management you have full history. You'll need another system that allows ssh connections with sparkle also.

We tried a multiuser Sparkle and setup collapsed because one user anned a copy of a git project by accident and a mysterious recursion developed that filled up a hard disk.

No such trouble happened with one user setups.

We have also had good results with OwnCloud. Server side config is slightly more elaborate there. Behaves almost exactly like Dropbox for workstations.

Comment: Good answer actually but looks like what I need is not possible for free.
You inspired me though, I am thinking about a python script that would run on intervals or something to sync the desktop content with some other folder some where else and that other folder may be synced in turn with Dropbox; thus free, private, auto sync.